# Responsive CSS improvement issue

Tags: css

I started to write a mobile version in css and I am asking you which is the better way:

1. In the html to write a `div` which has a class **desktop** and another `div` which has a class **mobile**. And build everthing from zero. For instance:

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-1 desktop1">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-5 despre-noi-text first-section">
   <h2>asdfsdfdf</h2>
     <p class="despre-paragraph">
           adsdadd
            </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 despre-noi-img second-section"></div>
 </div>
 
</div>
<div class="container-fluid mobile1">
 <div class="container">
  <div class ="row mobile-row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 mobile1-img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class ="row mobile-row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 mobile1-text">
    <h2>asdfsdffdfsfsdf</h2>
      <p class="mobile1-despre-paragraph">
               asdfdfdfd 
             </p>
             <p class="mobile1-despre-paragraph2">saddfsdfsdfsdfd</p>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And after that I will check with media queries on the mobile resolution which classes will be hidden and which will be not hidden.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

 .desktop1  { display:none; }
 .mobile1  { display:block; } 
 }
```

OR  to overwrite all of the classes in media queries ?

Comment: or maybe to use `hidden-xs` class (<768px)?

Comment: i would go to override the classes. That will help to have less html code avoiding duplicate info. Then in mediaquerie check for widths and override it all, imo. i would go for your first option if for example, if I got a menu.

Comment: The ideea is the design for desktop its not the same with the mobile version. Of course the colors and text are the same. I must write a lot position absolute css and to disables a lot of float, if i choose to overwrite the clasess. is it wise ? it will be a total css mess code

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use media queries to override the default properties. It's generally a good principle to keep your code DRY and easily maintainable. Having two versions of a block of HTML means unnecessary duplication (meaning more code needs to be loaded to the browser) and more work in future maintenance.

It's not a performance issue to use the queries to override the styles -- CSS is built to cascade. Don't feel bad about taking advantage of it (unless you're cascading with little reason and adding unnecessary specification).

Short answer: Save yourself the stress. Don't duplicate the HTML.